# How can you delete similar characters at the same positions in 2 strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

I need to figure out a  way to delete common characters from two strings if the common characters are in the same position, but it is not working and I am trying to figure this out. This is what I tried so far, it works for some strings, but as soon as the second string is larger than the first, it stops working. EDIT: I also need a way to store the result in a variable before printing it as I need to use it in another function.

Example :

ABCDEF and ABLDKG would result in the "ABD" parts of both strings to be deleted, but the rest of the string would remain the same
CEF and LKG would be the output

```
def compare(input1,input2):
if len(input1) < len(input2):
    for i in input1:
        posi = int(input1.find(i))
        if input1[num] ==  input2[num]:
            x =   input1.replace(i,"" )
            y =  input2.replace(i,"" )
         num = num+1

    print(x)
    print(y)
else:
    for i in input2:
        num = 0
        posi = int(input2.find(i))
        if input2[num] ==  input1[num]:
            input1 =  input1[0:num] + input1[num+1:(len(input1)+ 1 )] # input1.replace(i,"" )
            input2 =  input2[0:num] + input2[num+1:(len(input1) + 1)]
            x = input1
            y = input2

        num = num + 1
print(str(x))
print(str(y))
```

Comment: "... it stops working".  What is the problem?  What does it do?  Do you get an error stacktrace, it just stops, ...?  If it stops on a larger string, you could reverse the parameters , using the longer one as the first string.

Comment: you could use `zip_longest` from `itertools` ie `[''.join(k) for k in zip(*[i for i in zip_longest("ABCDEF","ABLDKG",fillvalue = "") if i[0]!=i[1]])]`

Comment: What does _it stops working_ mean, exactly? Please share a [mcve]. The indentation of your code looks broken, by the way.

Comment: If I test it with `compare('asdfq', 'aqdez')` it seems it doesn't even work with equal length strings, does it...? (result: `sdfq` and `qdez`)

Answer (score 2):

you could use

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a,b = "ABCDEF","ABLDKG"
[''.join(k) for k in zip(*[i for i in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue = "") if i[0]!=i[1]])]
['CEF', 'LKG']
```

You can wrap this in a function:

```
def compare(a, b):
    s = zip(*[i for i in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue = "") if i[0]!=i[1]])
    return [''.join(k) for k in s]


 compare("ABCDEF","ABLDKG")
['CEF', 'LKG']

 compare('asdfq', 'aqdexyz')
['sfq', 'qexyz']
```

Comment: This did work, but is there a way to store the thing returned in a variable. Like stated before, I am new to python and tried to store the ''.join(k) in a variable  named X as i would need it later, but it just said "x is not defined"

Comment: @HarvikKolla do `X = compare("ABCDEF","ABLDKG")`

Answer (score 0):

```
strlist = ["ABCDEF","ABLDKG"]
char_dict = dict()
for item in strlist:
    for char in item:
        char_dict[char] = char_dict.get(char,0) + 1
new_strlist = []
for item in strlist:
    new_strlist.append(''.join([char for char in item if char_dict[char] < 2]))
```

Note that this will convert strings that have only duplicates into empty strings rather than removing them altogether.